# R Shiny not deploying - An error has occured

Tags: r, shiny, deployment

My Shiny App is working pefect locally, but when I open it on Shiny App, it says this:

[An error has occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE4n5.png)

I already checked that all the libraries where included, and use the proper syntax for setting working directory. Alredy restarted RStudio to make sure the libraries environemnt is clean.

Any ideas of what could be the error?

Here is the code.

```
library(shiny)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(scales)
library(stringr)

setwd("C:/Users/52871/Downloads/R Programming/FP")
evpd <- read.csv("evpd.csv")
stockCars <- read.csv("stockCars.csv")
evpd <- subset(evpd, complete.cases(evpd))
stockCars <- subset(stockCars, complete.cases(stockCars))


ui <- navbarPage("Aplicación",    #--------------------- Nav Bar
                 
                 tabPanel("Models Selling",      #Tab Panel 1
  
  
  titlePanel("Sold Models by Make"),
  
      hr(),
  
      selectInput("make_dec", 
                  label ="Select Make",
                  choices = c("TESLA", "AUDI", "NISSAN", "KIA", "CHEVROLET", "FIAT", "FORD",
                              "BMW", "TOYOTA", "VOLVO", "MERCEDES-BENZ")
      ),
      plotOutput("makePlot"),
  hr(),
  em("Each Make has its own top models and units sold from 2010 to 2021.
Data is represented in descending order in a bar graph for visualization purposes.
After the chart, a table with the values is shown, after selecting the desired Make"),
  p(),
  dataTableOutput('tabla')
  ),                     #---------------------closing tabpanel 1

  
  tabPanel("By Brands",   #---------------------tab panel 2            
           
         
           titlePanel("Make by Year by Electric Vehicle Type"),
           
           hr(),
           
           plotOutput("makeScatter"),
           hr(),
           em("Top 8 Car Makes Overtime Viewing: whether they prefer to produce battery-electric
              Vehicles or Plugin Hybrid Electric Vehicles. There is data from 2010, but there is
              2010 is here, and we can see the best manufacturers producing them."),
           em("Some of the insights we are able to see are that BWM opted for plug-in hybrid electric
              Vehicles were first, followed by Ford and Kia.On the other side, Tesla starts
              to produce them considerably, but they prefer battery-electric vehicles. Nissan, Tesla,
              and Volkswagen did not manufacture Plugin Hybrid Electric Vehicles")
  ),                     #closing tabpanel 2-----------------------------------------
  
  tabPanel("5 Top Models Sold",    #Tab Panel 3 -------------------------------
           
         
           titlePanel("Most Popular Models in the last 10 years"),
           
           plotOutput("makeBoxplot"),
           hr(),
           em("Tesla has three models on the Top 5 list of popular electric cars. Model Y and Model 3
           are the two most popular models, with the Model S ranking fifth.Nissan, with its
           The Leaf Model is third, followed by Chevrolet's Boltev.")
  ),   #closing tabpanel c-----------------------------------------------------
  
  tabPanel("Electric Cars Boom",    #Tab Panel 4 -------------------------------
           
           
           titlePanel("Make by Year by Electric Vehicle Type"),
           
           hr(),
           
           plotOutput("makeBarElectric"),
           
           hr(),
           
           em("The electric range of each brand is the number of miles an EV can travel.
          can travel on a fully charged battery or a single charge.On this
          chart, we added the total electric range of each Make to summarize which
          When it comes to Electric Ranges, make has the most capacity."),
           p(),
           em("Tesla has been dominating and taking care of the majority of the market since 2013. BMW,
           Chevrolet and Nissan trail Tesla, coming in second, third, and fourth in different
           years. 2013 to 2020")
  ),
  
  tabPanel("Richest Countries/Car Stocks", #Tab Panel 5 --------------------------
           
           
           titlePanel("Richest Countries with the best Car Stock Value Over the Years"),
           
           hr(),
           
           plotOutput("makeScatterStock"),
           
           hr(),
           
           em("The stock market value of each Make is measured in each country in the world. We possess
              information about some of the countries, and the top country on the chart is China.
              Stocks value was added up to summarize and be able to visualize the power of China, followed by USA"),
           em("By removing China and USA from the plot, we are able to have a better resolution
              for the remaining countries. We can see the chart here:"),
           hr(),
           plotOutput("makeScatterStock2"),
           hr()
  ),  
  
  
  tabPanel("Energy provider used by Top 5 Makes", #Tab Panel 6 ----------------------------------
           
           
           titlePanel("Each Make needs its own Energy Provider for their Cars"),
           
           hr(),
           
           plotOutput("makeBarUtility"),
           
           hr(),
           
           em("As we can see in the charts, Puget Sound Energy is the main energy provider.
            for the Top 5 Manufacturers of Electric Vehicles.After, Bonneville Power
            Line's administration would be the second provider.Not that each bar chart
            shows the total number of providers used but does not make a comparison
            It refers to each company's 100 percent share of value.")
  ),   #Closing Panel
  
  tabPanel("Electric Vehicle Modes", #Tab Panel 7 ---------
        
           
           
           titlePanel("Advancement of Electric Cars"),
           
           hr(),
           
           plotOutput("makeLines"),
           
           hr(),
           
           em("We are mainly able to have 2 types or modes of electric cars: Battery Electric
            Vehicles or Plugin Hybrid Electric Vehicles. While the battery-electric vehicle
            Plug-in hybrid electric vehicles use only energy as a fuel source, and they have a battery.
            a tank for gasoline. You have the option to switch between electric and gasoline fuel.
            for the Hybrid")
  ),   #Closing Panel
  
  tabPanel("Electric Range Vehicle Levels",    #Tab Panel 8 ----------------------------
           
           
           titlePanel("Low, Medium and High Electric Range Vehicles"),
           
           hr(),
           
           plotOutput("makeRange"),
           
           hr(),
           
           em("The electric range of each car is its travel capacity on a charge.
            On this data, we have cars that go from 0 miles (not electric at all) to 377 miles per charge.
            We have assigned intervals to these numbers in order to categorize the Electric Range as Low, Medium, or High.
            or High. We can see the capacities of different makes in the chart, and of course
            Tesla has the units with the most electric range on the market, followed by Chevrolet.")
  )   #Closing Panel
  
)


# Define server logic -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$makePlot <- renderPlot({
    
    evpd %>%   
      as.data.frame() %>%
      filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
      arrange(desc(Model)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=fct_infreq(Model), fill=Model)) +
      geom_bar() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom",
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=12),
            title = element_text(size=12),
            text = element_text(size=16)
            ) +
      labs(x="Different Models", y="Number of Units sold",
           title="Car Models of each Make") +
      scale_fill_hue(c=45, l=80)
      
    
  })
  
  output$tabla <- renderDataTable({
    
      evpd %>%
      filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
      group_by(Make, Model) %>%
      summarise(n = n(),.groups = 'drop') %>% 
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      datatable(colnames=c("Make", "Model", "Units")) 

    #evpd %>% filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
     # count(Model) 
  })
  
  output$makeScatter <- renderPlot({
    
    evpd %>%
      filter(Model.Year > 2008) %>%
      mutate(Model.Year = as.factor(Model.Year)) %>%
      subset(Make %in% names(sort(table(evpd$Make), decreasing = T)[1:8])) %>%
      group_by(Model.Year, Make, Model, Electric.Vehicle.Type) %>%
      summarise(n = n(),.groups = 'drop') %>%
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Make, y=Model.Year, color=Make)) +
      geom_jitter(size=3) +
      facet_grid(. ~Electric.Vehicle.Type) +
      theme(legend.position="bottom",
            axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=12),
            text = element_text(size=16)
            ) +
      guides(color="none")
    
  })
  
  output$makeBoxplot <- renderPlot({
    
    evpd %>% group_by(Model.Year, Make, Model) %>%
      subset(Model %in% names(sort(table(evpd$Model), decreasing = T)[1:5])) %>%
      summarise(n= n(),.groups = 'drop') %>%
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Model, n), y=n, color=Make)) +
      geom_boxplot(size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x=Model, xend=Model, y=0, yend=n)) +
      theme(legend.position="bottom",
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=12),
            text = element_text(size=16)
            ) +
      labs(x="Top Models", y="Units Sold", title="The top 10 best Models sold ever since 2000") +
      facet_grid()
  })
  
  output$tabla <- renderDataTable({
    
    evpd %>%
      filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
      group_by(Make, Model) %>%
      summarise(n = n(),.groups = 'drop') %>% 
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      datatable(colnames=c("Make", "Model", "Units")) 
    
  })
  
  output$makeBarElectric <- renderPlot({
    
    evpd %>% arrange(desc(Electric.Range)) %>%
      subset(Make %in% names(sort(table(evpd$Make), decreasing = T)[1:8])) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Model.Year, y=Electric.Range, fill = Make)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
      xlim(2012,2021) +
      theme_grey() + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#99FFCC", "#66CCCC", "#006666", "#3366CC", 
                                 "#9933CC", "#CC66CC", "#990066", "#FF3333")) +
      theme(text = element_text(size=16))
    
  })
  
  
  output$makeScatterStock <- renderPlot({
    
    stockCars %>% group_by(region) %>%
      summarize(mean_value = mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
      arrange(desc(mean_value)) %>%
      slice(-1) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=mean_value, y=reorder(region,mean_value))) +
      geom_point(aes(color=region), size=6) +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            text = element_text(size=16)) +
      scale_x_continuous(labels=comma) +
      labs(x="Mean Stock Value", y="Countries")
    
  })
  
  output$makeScatterStock2 <- renderPlot({
    
    stockCars %>% group_by(region) %>%
      summarize(mean_value = mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
      arrange(desc(mean_value)) %>%
      slice(-1:-3) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=mean_value, y=reorder(region,mean_value))) +
      geom_point(aes(color=region), size=6) +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            text = element_text(size=16)) +
      scale_x_continuous(labels=comma) +
      labs(x="Mean Stock Value", y="Countries")
    
  })
  
  output$makeBarUtility <- renderPlot({
    
    evpd <- evpd[-which(evpd$Electric.Utility == ""), ] #erasing empty values from specific column
    
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("BONNE", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Bonneville Power Administration"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("PUGE", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Puget Sound Energy"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("CITY", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Cities"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("PACIF", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Pacific Corp"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("MODERN", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Modern Electric Water Company"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("PUD", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "PUD of Grant County"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("AVIST", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Avista Corporation"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("OKANO", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Okanoga County Electric Corp"
    evpd$Electric.Utility[grepl("PORTL", evpd$Electric.Utility)] <- "Portland General Electric Corp"
    
    evpd %>% arrange(desc(Electric.Range)) %>%
      subset(Make %in% names(sort(table(evpd$Make), decreasing = T)[1:5])) %>%
      ggplot(aes(y=Electric.Range, x=Make, fill=Electric.Utility)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill") +
      theme_gray() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ddc3a5", "#201e20", "#e0a96d", "#edca82", 
                                 "#669900", "#097770", "#e0cdbe", "#a9c0a6", "#e34543")) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
      labs(x="Top 5 Makes", y="Electric Energy Provided by Energy Companies") +
      theme(text = element_text(size=16))
    
  })
  
  output$makeLines <- renderPlot({
    
    stockCars %>% group_by(powertrain, year) %>%
      summarise(mean_n=mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
      arrange(desc(mean_n)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(year), y=mean_n, group=powertrain, color=powertrain)) +
      geom_line(size=1.5)  +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar) +
      labs(title="Battery Electric Vehicles VS Plugin Hybrid Electric Vehiceles",
           x="Year", y="Mean of Sum of total Stock Value") +
      theme_grey() +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("#ddc3a5", "#201e20"), name = "Electric Vehicle Modes",
                         breaks = c("BEV", "PHEV"),
                         labels=c("Battery Electric Vehicles", "Plugin Hybrid Electric Vehicles")) +
      theme(text = element_text(size=16))
    
  })
  
  output$makeRange <- renderPlot({
    
    evpd %>% mutate(ElectricRange = cut(evpd$Electric.Range, breaks = c(55, 140, 220,376), 
                                        labels = c("Low Electric Range", "Medium Electric Range", 
                                                   "High Electric Range"))) %>%
      subset(Make %in% names(sort(table(evpd$Make), decreasing = T)[1:5])) %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Make, y=Model.Year, color=ElectricRange)) +
      geom_jitter(alpha=0.7) +
      ylim(2010,2021) +
      facet_grid(~ElectricRange) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("#ddc3a5", "#edca82", "#097770"),
                         breaks = c("Low Electric Range", "Medium Electric Range", "High Electric Range"),
                         labels= c("55 - 140 miles","141-220 miles","221-376 miles")) +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1),
            text = element_text(size=16))
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is the last message I have from Deploy Log

"Deployment completed: https://vexkqm-humberto-hernandez.shinyapps.io/4657/
Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) :
unable to identify current timezone 'H':
please set environment variable 'TZ'
2: Error detecting locale: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE): string multibyte 3 inválida
(Using default: en_US) "

Comment: Please try to provide a _minimal_ reproducible example, there is a LOT going on there, I think your problem can likely be reproduced in far fewer than 375 lines. Try pushing a "hello world" app with 1-2 UI elements, then progressively add 1-2 more UI elements and 1 block of `server` code at a time. When you finally can reproduce the same error, come back with that reduced app. Also, please confirm that while the last line shows that clear error, are there any lines of output that might indicate other issues, perhaps warnings or other "not quite right" lines of output.

Comment: Further, the `unable to identify current timezone 'H'` is very odd to me. There's nothing obvious in your code here that suggests you are using `POSIXt`-class variables. Have you done what it said by setting the `TZ` envvar before deploying? Have you set it within your shiny app as well?

Comment: Last ... you have several uses of `== input$something`, but you aren't guarding against empty input elements. While it might not always fail, as code becomes more complex, it is highly likely that a reactive block will fire off before _all_ inputs are filled, in which case `input$make_dec` (as one example) might be `NULL`, noting that `.. %>% filter(Make == input$make_dec)` will fail with an error if `input$make_dec` is null. While typically empty input elements should be `""`, reactivity can occur too aggressively. Look up `req`, `validate`, and `need`.

Comment: I already get rid of the TZ error, I added this line of code.  ``` Sys.setenv(TZ="America/Cancun") ```. But in the Deploy Log I'm still getting the warning message _Error detecting locale: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE): string multibyte 3 inválida
 (Using default: en_US)_ .  [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SF-D82ILu-Jnj1NVjs-2hi2kNgRVG9q6/view?usp=share_link) you can see a screenshot of the app. Just the 1st TabPanel interacts with the user.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uQ9gDn2dxgHQY4LU9nxyfdcbkAa2Tirb/view?usp=sharing) the CSV files.

Comment: (Correction, the TZ part is a warning, not an error. I think it is likely due to similar reasons that you get the real error about the locale.) Try seeing what your local (not-yet-deployed) locale is with `Sys.getlocale()`. For me, it returns `"LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8;..."`. From there, try to explicitly set `LC_ALL`, which using my example would be `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United States.utf8")` (please use your own locale in place of English).

Comment: @r2evans My local settings are _[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"_, so I added _Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English_United States.1252")_ Right? Still not working, now it says _Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE): string multibyte 3 inválida
 (Using default: en_US)_